# 2015 VW Jetta ODB codes

Tags: vw, jetta

What would be the most likely cause of my 2015 Jetta throwing both the P0496 (Evaporative emission system high purge flow) and the P0442 (Evaporative emission system leak detected) codes?

Comment: Did you check the fuel cap?

Comment: I did and it *looks* fine. The seal wasn't cracked or bad looking and I made sure it was closed and clicked like it says to. I had thought about buying a new one just in case, but wasn't sure that would cause the high purge flow error.

Comment: If you checked the cap, did you try and clear the codes ... did they come back right away?

Comment: One of them (can't remember which) was "permanent". The guy at Advanced said that meant I would have to go to the dealer to get that turned off. I was out in the sticks at the time and have not had a chance to go by a dealer. So, no, haven't cleared the codes.

Comment: [This page](https://www.obd-codes.com/p0496) also says to replace the purge solenoid valve, which if the fuel cap doesn't fix it, would be the next step. I've never heard of a standard code which was permanent. You could try disconnecting the battery for about 30 minutes. This would most likely wipe your stereo settings, but if should also wipe the code on the ECU.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  The Permanent term is used starting in the 2009 OBD system to denote the fact that codes are no longer cleared when the clear command is sent.  The MIL goes out and then the PCM keeps running the monitors until it sees no failures and then it erases the codes.  I like this new feature, I can still see what the codes were even when someone just "erased" them.